# Is there a way to validate a date field format using Drools guided rule editor?

Tags: drools, jbpm

Using the drools guided rule editor (version 6.3.0 FINAL) I am able to check if a date is before or after a date value. There isn't an option to simply confirm if a date is valid, for example confirm it's in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".  Can this be done using the guided rule editor?

Comment: What data type is the Date you want to validate?

Comment: It's defined as a date field in the drools fact but the source data is defined as a string. Basically want to confirm the string is a valid date format.